# How to create a data frame in the success/number of trials format for elrm starting from excel

Tags: r, excel, statistics, logistic-regression

I'm trying to generate a data frame in the  success/number of trials syntax in order to proceed with an Exact logistic regression (as shown here https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/exact-logistic-regression/). The aim is to produce something as follows

```
##     female apcalc admit ntrials
## 0.0      0      0     1       8
## 1.0      1      0     1       6
## 0.1      0      1     7      10
## 1.1      1      1     6       6
```

Each of the variables I have to consider is already coded as binary, and I have them arranged in columns (each row corresponding to an observation) via excel file (which I feed R as working database).

I've tried searching the website with no clear reference to this issue in particular, with this format of data frame.

I guess the real question here is : how do I generate such data frame starting from an excel file arranged as illustrated?

Comment: Is your question about how to create a data frame from an Excel file? Try https://readxl.tidyverse.org/ or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your time, Jon. In the following I'll refer to the data used in the UCLA example. My doubts remain about the generation of the "n trials" and "admit" columns, as how to count the total number of trials and admission for each interaction between the elements "female" and "apcalc" (**i.e**  _How many female students that had took advanced calculus classes have been admitted? Out of how many that applied in total of the same group?_) . Could you please suggest me a coding example to read regarding the task, or provide one yourself? Sorry for my lack of exp, I'm loving learning ds!

Comment: Quoting the reference to the tidyverse package, I also came across dplyr; it should allow an easier manipulation of the data into frames if I understood correctly.

Comment: `dplyr` is a good tool for that sort of thing. Here's a relevant tutorial: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html